# Unable to find Documents on iPad device when mounted

Tags: linux-mint, mount, devices, ios

It seems that this is a common problem, but there haven't been any satisfactory solutions posted yet, despite existing for years.

Briefly, the problem is that when I mount my iPad in Linux Mint, I cannot find the "Documents on My iPad" device that everyone claims appears automatically. The other one, just "My iPad" appears fine with the generic folders inside for books and pictures.

I need to be able to find that device in order to move some movies over, but it seems like no one is sure how to do it. I've tried restarting everything, reinstalling libimobiledevice, and anything else that's been suggested before. Here are the other questions which are essentially the same, but never properly resolved:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/575197/can-not-see-documents-on-nicks-ipad-device-when-plugging-my-ipad-into-my-ubun?rq=1

https://askubuntu.com/questions/442511/mounting-ipad-in-ubuntu-13-10-cant-find-documents-on-ipad-device?rq=1

https://askubuntu.com/questions/490227/cant-find-documents-on-usernames-ipad-in-12-04-with-an-ipad-mini?rq=1

I'm running Mint 17.2 on a fresh install (literally just the other day), 64-bit, and it's an iPad 4 with iOS 8. If there's any other information you need let me know. If anyone else is in the same situation, could you verify that you either can or cannot see the device in question?

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an old thread but I couldn't find a solution online last night so it seems to still be a problem. BTW, I did this on Mint 18. I figured out that if I eject and reconnect to my iPhone 6, the folders would start to show up. Try it a couple times. By this I merely mean clicking on the small eject symbol next to the device in the explorer and then clicking on the device to open it up. Hope that helps.